# ServerlessError: Documentation part already exists while deploying Serverless AWS apigateway

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, aws-api-gateway

I am getting [ServerlessError: Documentation part already exists] while deployment when I have updated the version in documentation object from version:"8.0.2" to  version:"9.0.1".

[serverlessErrorImage1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKBus.png)
[serverlessErrorImage2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ils1L.png)

But it succeed when run deployment again by updating version in documentation object from version:"9.0.1" to  version:"9.0.2".

```
custom:
  documentation:
    api:
      info:
        version: "9.0.2"
        title: "Mock APIs"
        description: "Mock Apis for my new project"
```

I am unable to understand how serverless-aws-documentation versioning is working while deployment.